# Update Joomla without working Backend (PHP version was updated)

Tags: php, update

My provider recently removed an older PHP version and I forgot to update one of the Joomla installations. Now I'm left with a broken front- and backend that only shows me

> [image]

What now? Is there any way I can fix this. I have of course ftp access to the site. Is there any good description of how to proceed?

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? You'd be best off contacting your hosting provider as this message is not displayed by the Joomla CMS

Comment: @Lodder What I see from the `Readme` in the installation it's 3.4, but I'm not sure how many updates I have installed after the initial installation. Or is the `Readme` updated as well?

Comment: Maybe it is possible to extract and copy a new installation to the server without altering with the config, templates, etc?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: It says `5.5.38` while in my `index.php` the min-version is defined as `5.3.10`.

Comment: @Lodder Ok, thanks for holding my hand :) It turns out, I could edit `.htaccess` and increase the ancient version that is referenced there. It is working again.

Answer (score 2):

The fix was easy. The problem was the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of the installation. There, you find at the very beginning something like this

```
AddHandler php55-cgi .php
```

In my case, this pointed to `php53-cgi` which my provider did not support any longer. I looked up, what versions are available now and found a listing:

[image]

After editing the `.htaccess` file and manually setting it to `php5-cgi` I could access my site again and update the Joomla installation. After the update, `.htaccess` now points to `php55`.

Comment: Just FYI, be sure to use PHP 7 as this will boost your performance by 200%

Comment: Handling the server's php handler on the htaccess is not a standard in what Joomla provides as a sample htaccess file and is not related with Joomla in any level.

Comment: @FFewin What is your point? If I knew that it was not Joomla related (although it was my Joomla page that stopped working), I wouldn't have asked on a Joomla site in the first place. After finding out that the problem was how my web-provider handles php I figured that someone might run into a similar problem and I better post my findings. Why are you so narrow-minded here? Obviously at least 4 people ran into similar problems.